# Lost keypair to elasticbeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Yesterday my SSD suddenly died when the PC was running. I have an AWS app where I had SSH access. But it's suddenly lost, and I have no backup for the key itself (which is a security risk).

Now adding a new keypair requires me to terminate and relaunch the app. But the app has very critical data, and users connected 24x7.

I have access to the EC2, Elasticbeanstalk console from the web. I don't have ssh access, but I can successfully deploy the app with `eb deploy appname`.

Because I can deploy the app, I can read any content and write that to the logs as well. Is it possible to pull key from the server? Or is there any hope to recover the old key?

Answer (score 1):

Usually Elasticbeanstalk supports [AWS Systems Manager Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html) out of the box. Thus in most cases you can connect to your EB instance with the manger through AWS Console.

You can find it if you got to EC2 consoles, find your instance, and then you will have **Connect** button.